# How to share log files with multiple processes?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, logging, pipe

This is more design question to hear ideas from other people.
I'm writing a software written in c language completely.

It has multiple processes running and now I'm thinking to add logging.
First idea is writing a simple log function may be in separate library.
Then, I may need to add some kind of lock to prevent race condition to access the log file.

The second idea is spawning a separate log process and the log process is accessing the log file.
And the other processes can send log message to the log process using IPC mechanism such as pipe or unix socket.

In that case, is there any way to set buffer for the pipe or unix socket?
Or it is not worth to consider buffering for IPC recipient?

Comment: If you can get the same file descriptor to all processes and the file descriptor has O_APPEND mode, you can use that. And all sockets have buffers.

Comment: Linux has `syslogd` built in; maybe you just want to use that?    https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/vsyslog.3.html   https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd

Comment: If I use O_APPEND mode, can I open a same file from multiple processes and add messages to the same file? In that case, I assume I still need locking mechanism. Will it be good idea to use binary semaphore for this case? Or do you want to recommend something else?

Comment: If the writes are small, they will be atomic and you don't need any locking.

Comment: Also, please let me know if you want point out any problem if I go to the direction to use separate logger process.

Comment: oh good point, you don't even need to share the FD with O_APPEND mode. Each process can just open it. I was thinking of without that mode, when you'd need it to be shared.

Comment: Make sure that each message written by a process properly identifies the process writing the message (program name, PID) and is appropriately timestamped, and that the log message format is uniform across the programs sharing the log file.  There's nothing more exasperating than looking at a message in a log file and wondering which program wrote the message!  And make sure that you end up using a single `write()` call to get the data for a single message to the log file.  There's an issue of efficiency; more importantly, there's the issue of atomicity for the messages.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  If you make multiple calls to write a single message, you will sooner or later get parts of messages interleaved in the log file, which is close to disastrous when it comes to understanding the logs.  It's better, IMO, to use a separate log file per process, but if you are going to share a single log file, make sure you achieve atomicity — a single call to `write()` for each message.  The advice about O_APPEND is totally relevant too.  And think about log rotation — how do you limit the size of the log files and switch to a new one when the file gets too big.

Comment: Use a dedicated log process to write to the logfile. Use POSIX shared memory to communicate log messages to the log process. All log messages should have the process id of the process that generated the log message and the timestamp. For reading the logged messages, any process can open the log file in the read only mode and read.

Comment: I originally thought to use Unix socket or pipe to send log contents to the dedicated log process. Is it going to be a bad idea?